# Wacom intuos5 disable touch by default

Tags: wacom

How do I disable the touch usage on my tablet by default when I plug it in.

Normally when I plug it in I open a terminal type "xinput" get the ID which has been id=18 and id=23, it changes. Then "xinput disable id". I would like my to have this off by default as I simply do not use the touch interface.

Answer (score 0):

out it into your startup applications as a script.

power key, type "startup" , startup applications, add, put your script in

```
bash "/home/...wherever/DisableTouchscreen.sh"
```

seeing as the id to often changes on reboot this is for my touchscreen as per xinput *ELAN0732:00 .this is the script

```
list=$(xinput | grep $search | grep pointer)

device_id=$(echo "$list" | sed -n 's/.*ELAN0732:00.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p')

for i in $device_id do echo

xinput disable $i

done
```

this probably disables both touchscreen and pen, but the pen activates when I use it for the first time for any given session.